# Batch create folders based on filename

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with 100s of archive files (rar and zip). To unpack all these files into individual folders, I wanted to create a folder for each filename.
Filenames are structured like "1111 2222_blablabla.rar", with at least one empty space in the filename.

I managed to use the script to create the folders which works with individual files:

```
set str=%1
set str=%str:~0,-5%
mkdir %str%
```

But when I try to integrate this into a script for the whole folder, "set" doesn't work anymore.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.rar) do (
set str=%f
set str=%str:~0,-5%
mkdir %str%
)
rem here will come the rar command
endlocal
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot,

jmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
for %%f in (*.rar) do if not exist "%%~nf\" md "%%~nf"
```

For each `.rar` file, create a folder (if it still does not exist) with the name (without extension) of the file

Your code fails for two reasons

1 - variables inside a block of code (lines enclosed in parenthesis) are replaced with the value in the variable before starting to execute the block. If any variable changes its value inside the block, it is not accesible from inside the same block. You need to use delayed expansion (`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`) and, where needed, change the syntax from `%var%` into `!var!` to indicate to the parser that the access to the variable value must be delayed until the command execution

2 - If the string contains spaces, the command `mkdir 1111 2222_blablabla` will create two folders, not just one. File/folder references that contain spaces should be quoted

Answer (score 0):

`enabledelayedexpansion` is just half the deal. It allows you to update the value of a variable but to access the modified value you have to use `!str!` instead of `%str%`. This should do the trick.

Comment: yes. ... and using `set str=%%f` instead of `set str=%f` in OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a batch file for this task when using **Rar.exe** or **WinRAR.exe**:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -ad *.rar "Path\To\Destination\Folder\"
```

The "secret" is the switch `-ad` which is exactly for tasks like this.

Using GUI of WinRAR:

1. Select all the *.rar or *.zip archives.
2. Click on **Extract To** in toolbar.
3. Select the destination folder.
4. Check the option *Extract archives to subfolders* in group *Miscellaneous*.
5. Click on button **OK**.

Text file **Rar.txt** in program files folder of WinRAR contains explanation for all commands and optional switches of console version **Rar.exe**.

Help of *WinRAR* open with a click on **Help topics** in menu help contains on **Contents** tab also explanation for all commands and switches for **WinRAR.exe** under list item *Command line mode*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It seems it's working now. The finished code is

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.rar) do (
md "%%~nf" 
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\unrar.exe" x "%%f" "%%~nf")
endlocal
```

Since there isn't any chance of repeating folders, I just removed what wasn't necessary.

And just when I was posting this I saw Mofi's reply. well, anyway I learned something more about batch editing.